# When does a Remote desktop's clipboard's content get transferred to the RDP client machine for copy or paste?

Tags: windows, clipboard, copy-paste, remote-desktop

During the RDP session from client A to server B, when one clicks copy on server B to transfer some text via shared clipboard to A,when does the clipboard actually being transferred to A,
is it right after copy action on B, or after paste action on A?

Also if client A also connected to server C, and copying from B to C, does the contents of clipboard get buffed on A before being transferred to C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did a bit of research myself and after looking at this [MSDN RDP Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc241066.aspx)  and in particular copy and paste examples my conclusion is that the clipboard contents only transferred during paste phase. Once the copy action is performed client receives only the format information (i.e Metafile,Palette etc)

> The goal of the Copy Sequence is to synchronize the list of available formats across the client and the server clipboards ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc241085.aspx))

Actual clipboard data is transferred during the paste phase

> The goal of the Paste Sequence is to transfer the data for a single format from the Shared Clipboard Owner to the Local Clipboard Owner. ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc241086.aspx))

Hence no data gets transferred until you click paste (here is a nice [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc241084.aspx)), however I couldn't find any answers to what happens when copy/paste is performed within the server B will data still be transferred to A?
Again RDP seems to have a concept of Local vs Shared Clipboard owners so chances are that data will not get sent to A, I have no proof of that though. Hope this helps someone